# How to speed up LU decomposition in Eigen C++?

Tags: c++, eigen, matrix-factorization

I am new to c++ and the Eigen library. I want to perform LU decomposition (partial pivoting) on a matrix of size `1815 X 1815`, with complex entries. However, the performance of my code is bad, the LU decomposition is taking `77.2852` seconds, compared to MATLAB taking only `0.140946` seconds. Please find the attached code. Any advice on how I can improve the code? Please note that in the first part of the code, I am importing the matrix from a file with entries: `a + bi`, where `a` and `b` are complex numbers. The matrix file was generated from MATLAB. Thank you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <fstream>
#include <complex>
#include <string>
#include <chrono> 

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono; 
using namespace Eigen;

int main(){ 

    int mat_sz = 1815; // size of matrix
    MatrixXcd c_mat(mat_sz,mat_sz); // initialize eigen matrix
    double re, im;
    char sign;
    string entry;

    ifstream myFile("A_mat"); // format of entries : a + bi. 'a' and 'b' are complex numbers

    //Import and assign matrix to an Eigen matrix

    for (int i = 0; i < mat_sz; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < mat_sz; j++){
            myFile >> entry;

            stringstream stream(entry);
            stream >> re >> sign >> im;
            c_mat(i,j) = {re, (sign == '-') ? -im : im}; // Assigning matrix entries
        }
    }

    // LU Decomposition

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    c_mat.partialPivLu(); // Solving equation through partial LU decomposition

    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);

    double million = 1000000;

    cout << "Time taken by function: " << duration.count()/million << " seconds" << endl; 

}
```

Comment: Are you compiling it with optimization turned on?

Comment: Mostly general advice, but still: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_do_I_get_good_performance.3F

Comment: Eigen is template heavy, and therefore requires optimizations to be turned on so that it gets inlined. Please add your compiler and flags and what hardware you're running this on.

Comment: @user253751 I don't think optimization is turned on. How can I check? I am using codelite as IDE.

Comment: @AviGinsburg I am using gcc version 7.4.0 on ubuntu. Hardware: Intel i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8. I am not sure about flags, how can I check it? Can you please also advise how I can enable the optimization? I typed g++ -Q --help=optimizers on my terminal and got a long list, e.g. falign-loops [disabled]. Is that in the right direction?

Comment: @K.se How do you compile your file/project? If on the command line (e.g. `$ gcc -O3 -march=native -Wall file.cpp`), what is the command? If using something like cmake, show that as well.

Comment: @AviGinsburg Great, thank you very much!! I was using -O0 earlier in my IDE. Now, I compiled as follows:  
g++ -O3 -march=native -Wall -I/home/.../eigen-eigen-323c052e1731/ A_mat_import_lu.cpp
The runtime is about 1.2 seconds. Using Ofast instead of O3, the runtime is about 1 seconds. However, this is still ~ 7 times slower than using lu() in MATLAB. Is that normal? Or, I could get something faster with Eigen?

Comment: Your Eigen code is using double precision floating point computations, I don't know what Matlab uses. You can change the matrix type to `MatrixXcf` and see if that gives you similar performance. You can also link against MKL or similar (I think that may help, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look into the Intel MKL. Can it be used with Eigen? Or, I have to choose between one of them? Using float did half the running time, however, I'll keep it to double since I am working with 15 digits decimals. Many thanks

Comment: @AviGinsburg I have linked Eigen with MKL (with the OpenMP threading option). Indeed, there is a great improvement in the runtime. The LU decomposition takes about 0.17 seconds (very close to that of MATLAB). Thank you. [SOLUTION]

Links: 
1. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html
2. https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-mkl-for-linux

Comment: @K.se please don't post solutions as comments! You can answer your own question.

Comment: Try `--ffast-math`. Validate some of the results to make sure it works. For complex matrix algebra, speedups are huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize the comments into an answer.

When you feel that `Eigen` is running slow there are a list of things that should be verified.

1. **Are optimizations turned on?**
   Eigen is a template heavy library that does a lot of compile time checks and that should be optimized out. If optimizations are not on, none of it gets inlined and many pointless function calls are made. Turning on even the lowest level of optimizations usually alleviates most of this (`-O1` or higher in gcc/clang, `/O1` or higher in MSVC). General notes on optimizations can be [found here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Optimization).
2. **Am I utilizing all the hardware options?**
   A lot of code in Eigen can be vectorized if allowed. Make sure that this is enabled with flags turning on SSE/AVX/etc. if the target hardware supports it. Enable FMA if available as well. There's a placeholder [doc here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicVectorization.html).
3. **Enable multithreading**
   If your process/hardware allow, consider [enabling OpenMP](http://view-source:http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) to allow Eigen to utilize multiple cores for some of the operations.
4. **Use the right precision**
   In many applications, only the first few digits matter. If this is the case in your application, consider using single precision instead of double precision.
5. **Link to a fine tuned library**
   In the end, Eigen spits out some finely built C++ code and relies on the compiler to handle most of the optimizations itself. In some cases, a more finely tuned library such as MKL may improve performance. [Eigen can link to MKL](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html) to squeeze a bit more speed out of the hardware.